# Разница хранения сессий между сервером и клиентом

Tags: php, node.js, сессия

`PHP`, к примеру, хранит сессионные данные на сервере, то есть создается файл с идентификатором, и в него записываются значения сессий в сериализованном виде (`$_SESSION['foo']='bar'`)

В `NodeJS` все обстоит по-другому: создается также файл с идентификатором, **но значения не записываются в него**, а записываются в объект запроса(`req.session.foo = 'bar'`). Файл сессия:

```
{
   "cookie": {
       "originalMaxAge":null,
        "expires":null,
        "httpOnly":true,
        "path":"/"},
        "__lastAccess":1479380096570
    }
}
```

Только служебная информация.

Получается, здесь значения сессий записываются у клиента? Но как?! Быть может я не до конца понимаю объект `req`...

Comment: А какой библиотекой вы пользуетесь для сессий в Node JS?

Comment: Пробовали `req.session.save();`?